# Flutter: How to delete folder in friebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I have a folder that i want to delete in firebase storage, i saw a similair question (outdated) which said that this wanst possible yet, is it now? and if not how can i go about it?

Answer (score 1):

of course you can do it !!

make sure that you read the storage docs probably  : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

```
      FirebaseStorage.instance
          .getReferenceFromUrl("url")
          .then((res) {
        res.delete().then((res) {
          print("Deleted!");
        });
      });
```

This will delete the file if you have the url ! , the best approach is to store the url in forestore , get it and then run something like the code above . best of luck !